# UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail with Tktinter

Tags: multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing, tk-toolkit

I want to create matplotlib figures in a python application with a tkinter GUI. The figure needs to be created with matplotlib and saved in a folder without being displayed in the GUI. To avoid blocking UI-features while the figure is being created, this has to be done in another thread. How do I draw the plot in a different thread than the one containing the tkinter root and frame?
I have classes Gui and View in two files gui.py for GUI managing and view.py for plot managing.

Here the piece of code:

############## from gui.py ##############

```
def run(self):
    
    for declaration_type in self.declaration_type:

        # init progress bar
        self.console_label.configure(text=f"Init...")
        sleep(1)
        self.progress_bar['value'] = 0
        self.progress_label.configure(text="LOADING 0%")
        i = 1

        # the json file where the output must be stored
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select Output folder.')
        if directory:
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                try: os.makedirs(directory)
                except: raise OSError("Can't create destination folder!")  

        data = DataLoader(self.input_file_entry.get(), self.report_list, self.report_type, self.appliance_type, declaration_type, self.fmm_var.get())

        for method in [SimulationMethod.BOOT, SimulationMethod.RAR, SimulationMethod.PICK]:           

            view = self.get_view_type(method, self.report_type, data, directory)

            # init progress bar
            sleep(1)
            self.progress_bar['value'] = 0
            self.progress_label.configure(text="LOADING 0%")
            i = 1
            
            self.console_label.configure(text=f"Simulating with {method.value} method...")
            sleep(1)
            
            for k in Utils.get_config().get('Output').get(declaration_type.value).get('Parameters'):
                view.execute_risk_analysis(k, method)
                self.progress_bar['value'] = (i/len(view.params_to_report.keys())*100)                
                self.progress_label.configure(text=f" LOADING {int(i/len(view.params_to_report.keys())*100)}%")
                i += 1

            if method in [SimulationMethod.BOOT, SimulationMethod.RAR]:
                view.prepare_excel(method)
        
            # init progress bar
            sleep(1)
            self.progress_bar['value'] = 0
            self.progress_label.configure(text="LOADING 0%")
            i = 1
            
            self.console_label.configure(text=f"Preparing {method.value} plots...")
            sleep(1)

            for k in Utils.get_config().get('Output').get(declaration_type.value).get('Parameters').keys():
                
                view.prepare_plot(k, method)
                self.progress_bar['value'] = (i/len(view.params_to_report.keys())*100)                
                self.progress_label.configure(text=f" LOADING {int(i/len(view.params_to_report.keys())*100)}%")
                i += 1

        logging.info(f"\n   fmm: {data.fmm}\n   report: {' '.join(data.report_list)}")
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("INFO",  "Done!\nCheck Output folder.")


def get_view_type(self, method, report_type, data, directory):

    if method in [SimulationMethod.BOOT, SimulationMethod.RAR]:
        return ViewRisk( report_type, data, directory)
    
    elif method in [SimulationMethod.PICK]:
        return ViewPick(report_type, data, directory)

def run_thread(self):

    # Call work function
    t = Thread(target=self.run)
    t.start()
```

############## from view.py ##############

```
def _plot(self, fig, feature, method, save):

    side = parameters.get(self.declaration_type).get('side').get(feature)
    risk_analysis, _, _ = super()._get_risk_and_report(method, feature)
    
    for idx, pick in enumerate(PickSubplot):
        ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, idx + 1)
        View._prepare_base_plot(ax, risk_analysis, pick, side)
        View._prepare_target_lines(ax, risk_analysis, pick, side)
        View._prepare_plot_string(ax, risk_analysis, pick)
   
    ViewPick._add_legend_elements(fig)
    ViewPick.__prepare_fig_title(fig, feature, self.declaration_type)    

    plt.ioff()
    
    if save:
        plt.savefig(f'{self._get_save_path(method)}\{feature}.png', format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.close()


def prepare_plot(self, fig, feature, method):

    self._plot(fig, feature, method, True)
```

The run_thread function is associated to a Tk button in the main window.

I have tried using the threading module, and managed to create a figure in another thread. However when I try to create a canvas with the figure the application crashes and outputs "UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail"